# AWS, using ec2-ssh fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

I installed the instagram ec2-ssh utility, as described here: http://instagram-engineering.tumblr.com/post/11399488246/simplifying-ec2-ssh-connections.

`ec2-host` works well, and lists the hosts.  For example:

```
legolas ec2-xx.xx.xx.xx.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com
```

However, when I try to login in via a name, I get an error:

```
[root@ip-xx.xx.xx.xx ec2-user]# ec2-ssh legolas
Connecting to send: 'POST / HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept-Encoding: identity\r\nContent-Length: 93\r\nUser-Agent: Boto/2.35.1 Python/2.6.9 Linux/3.14.27-25.47.amzn1.x86_64\r\nHost: ec2.us-west-1.amazonaws.com\r\nX-Amz-Date: 20150216T182656Z\r\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8\r\nAuthorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=AKIAxxx/20150216/us-west-1/ec2/aws4_request,SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-date,Signature=xxx\r\n\r\n'
send: 'Action=DescribeInstances&Filter.1.Name=tag%3AName&Filter.1.Value.1=legolas&Version=2014-10-01'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n'
header: Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
header: Transfer-Encoding: chunked
header: Vary: Accept-Encoding
header: Date: Mon, 16 Feb 2015 18:26:55 GMT
header: Server: AmazonEC2
ec2-xx.xx.xx.xx.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com.
ssh: Could not resolve hostname send:: Name or service not known
sh: line 1: send:: command not found
sh: line 2: reply:: command not found
sh: line 3: header:: command not found
sh: line 4: header:: command not found
sh: line 5: header:: command not found
sh: line 6: header:: command not found
sh: line 7: header:: command not found
sh: line 8: ec2-xx.xx.xx.xx.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com: command not found
```

Comment: I guess the first obvious question is: Does legolas have a security group with incoming port 22 open for SSH?

Comment: @monkeymatrix - yeah, if I just ssh to the hostname, it works, like so `ssh ec2-user@ec2-xx.xx.xx.xx.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com`

Comment: Ok. It looks like the error is that the hostname can't resolve. Is port 53 open on the machine you're running this from to allow it to conduct a DNS lookup?

Answer (score 0):

DNS Resolution should be enabled on your VPC. Follow below steps and try

1. Right click your VPC on AWS Web console
2. Select "Edit DNS Resolution"
3. Select "Yes" radio button
4. Click "Save"
5. Then try ec2-ssh again. It should work